# Rails validations and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my rails projects I have a lot of association tables. And I have some validations. Nothing really difficult, and it works almost every times.

But from time to time (like tonight), I have to switch from

```
  validates_presence_of :project_id
  validates_presence_of :tag_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :project_id, :scope => [:tag_id]
```

to

```
  validates_presence_of :project
  validates_presence_of :tag

  validates_uniqueness_of :project, :scope => [:tag]
```

Do you know the difference ? Do you if one is better than the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence

> 2.9 presence This helper validates that the specified attributes are not empty. It uses the blank? method to check if the value is either
>   nil or a blank string, that is, a string that is either empty or
>   consists of whitespace.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :login, :email, presence: true  
end
```

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, **you'll need to
>   test whether the associated object itself is present, and not the
>   foreign key used to map the association**.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  validates :order, presence: true
end
```

So, you should use the second example you gave, which tests if the **associated object itself is present**, and not the first example, which only tests if **the foreign key used to map the association is present**.